# Map part of the JSON to struct

Tags: rust

I have weather data API call and some json basic conversion:

```
use serde_json::{Value};

...

let resp = reqwest::get(WEATHER_API_URL).await?.text().await?;
let json: Value = serde_json::from_str(&resp)?;
```

which produces `Object` result:

```
Object({
    ...
    "clouds": Object({
        "all": Number(
            0,
        ),
    }),
    "id": Number(
        2950159,
    ),
    "main": Object({
        "feels_like": Number(
            287.04,
        ),
        "humidity": Number(
            34,
        ),
        "pressure": Number(
            1015,
        ),
        "temp": Number(
            288.56,
        ),
        "temp_max": Number(
            290.38,
        ),
        "temp_min": Number(
            287.03,
        ),
    })
    ...
```

I want only `main` data from that^ given shape.
I have a structure for that:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

...

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Main {
  temp: f32,
  feels_like: f32,
  temp_min: f32,
  temp_max: f32,
  pressure: f32,
  humidity: f32
}
```

How is it possible to map some part of `json` (the `main` object part) with my `Main` struct? Maybe there are better ways to accomplish such scenario? where basically what I need is grab some data from JSON and then be able to use it in my code. The key thing in my case is that my json has complex structure with nested entities and I can't map it one-to-one.

Comment: whats the weather api url? just curious

Comment: @rv.kvetch https://openweathermap.org/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a structs like:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MainWrapper {
  main: Main,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Main {
  temp: f32,
  feels_like: f32,
  temp_min: f32,
  temp_max: f32,
  pressure: f32,
  humidity: f32
}

let deserialized: MainWrapper = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;
```

Or if you don't want to deal with `MainWrapper` in your code:

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Main {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Main, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
        struct MainWrapper {
           main: MainInner,
        }

        // You can generally generate such copies with macros

        #[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
        struct MainInner {
           temp: f32,
           feels_like: f32,
           temp_min: f32,
           temp_max: f32,
           pressure: f32,
           humidity: f32
        }
        impl From<MapInner> for Main {
           // ...
        }

        let deserialized: MainWrapper = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Ok(deserialized.main.into())
    }
```

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you!